# How can I use GAN (Generative Adversarial Network) techniques that can help improve data ratios in a text dataset for neural network training?

Tags: string, dataset, generative-adversarial-network

I aim to train a neural network using a text data set. However, prior to the training process, I intend to utilize a GAN (Generative Adversarial Network) on the data set in order to address the insufficiency of data ratios. How can I accomplish this?

Lines from the DataSet

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.